# How to set column position in View

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can anyone please guide me how to set column position in View created for a Sharepoint Online List using PnP Powershell ?

I can't find option for position here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpview?view=sharepoint-ps

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **ViewFieldCollection.MoveFieldTo** method to set the column position in a view. Here is my demo for you:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael"
$ListName= "list"
$ViewName= "Test"
#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL
#Get the Context
$Context = Get-PnPContext
#Get the List View from the list
$ListView  =  Get-PnPView -List $ListName -Identity $ViewName
#Set Created field to first position. STARTS WITH 0.
$ListView.ViewFields.MoveFieldTo("Created",0)
$ListView.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for your help.